# Dynamically create time from 00:00:00 to 23:30:00( half hour difference with time format HH::mm:ss) in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, linq, datetime-format

I'm Setting up a dropdown of time dynamically, with format(HH:mm:ss),starting from 00:00:00 to 23:30:00. Is there any method to get this time format. Linq query is too appreciated.

Expected Result- 00:00:00, 00:30:00, 01:00:00, 01:30:00 to 11:30:00

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq3xN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Kendo time picker for this, which indeed have the format.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <div class="example-wrapper">
            <p>Select a date:</p>
            <kendo-timepicker
                [format]="'HH:mm:ss'"
                [steps]="steps"
                [value]="value"
            ></kendo-timepicker>
            <p>(↑ to increment and ↓ to decrement the value)</p>
        </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public steps: any = { hour: 0, minute: 30, second: 00 };
    public value: Date = new Date(2000, 2, 10, 10, 30);
}
```

for further info: Check this link: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/timepicker/incremental-steps/